# UpdatePanel works strange

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have an `UpdatePanel` and some controls within it, as you can see below. If I change a number in txtGoToPage textbox and press Enter, `GoToPage_TextChanged()` event handler is called. But if I enter first any page number other than 1, press Enter, and then enter number 1 again, after pressing Enter `GoToPage_TextChanged()` is not called. The same problem exists with `ddlPageSize` dropdown list. As you can see, by default the third item is selected. If I select another item, `ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged()` is called, but if after that I select the third (initially selected) item, `ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged()` is not called.

Could you please help me fix that?

Thanks.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlLicensing" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        ...
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Show rows:" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPageSize" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="20" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="50" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="100" Selected="True" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        &nbsp;
        Page 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtGoToPage" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
            OnTextChanged="GoToPage_TextChanged" CssClass="gotopage" onchange="JSSetSessionValue('ReloadLicensing', true);JSSetSessionValue('NewPageNumber', this.value)" />
        of
        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalNumberOfPages" runat="server" />                
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: To trouble shoot if it is Update Panel try 1: setting UpdateMode="Always" or 2: Remove UpdatePanel itself and see if it works if your code is not in UP.

Comment: I know it worked without UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling caching on the page, sometimes Update Panel and caching can have strange behavior combined.

Comment: Could you please tell me how I can disable caching on my UserControl that contains the UpdatePanel?

Comment: I added         Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching(); to Page_Init() of my UserControl, but it didn't help.

Comment: add the following code in page load event:
Response.ExpiresAbsolute=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Expires =-1500;
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
If it doesn't help then caching is not the problem

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this didn't help.

Comment: What version of ASP.net you have? 
Is there any specific attribute sets to your ScriptManager?
Can we see your "JSSetSessionValue" function? Maybe there's a problem with it on postback?